# Why is the array not being returned correctly?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class assign3 {
    public static int[] clist (int[] f) {
        List<Integer> gList = new ArrayList<>();
        int t = 0;
        int[] count = new int[1000];
        for (int i=0; i<f.length; i++) {
            if (gList.contains(f[i])) {
                t = gList.indexOf(f[i]);
                count[t]++;
            }
            else {
                gList.add(f[i]);
                t = gList.indexOf(f[i]);
                count[t] = 1;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] f = {1, 1, 3, 4, 5};
        System.out.println(clist(f));

    }
}
```

I'm trying to return the count array but it keeps returning:

`[I@e9e54c2`

Am I missing something? I tried to figure out if it was a syntactical error but there was no errors.

Comment: What you're seeing is the String returned from the `toString()` method of an int array. The duplicates will tell and show you how to extract the data from the array in a more logical and readable fashion.

Comment: For example, `System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(clist(f)));` might show what you want to show